# How to select one value and match with other value from my database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I use codeigniter and store my data **like 123,234** .

My table name is `schedule`  and column name `batch`.

```
$batch = 123;
$lot =1; 
$dataTest = $this->db->query("select q_set from schedule where lot='$lot' 
and batch='$batch'")->row();
```

see my image below

[image]

I try to select one value and match my sent value. ## how to match both the values ##

Comment: `and batch='$batch'` If `$batch` is 123 like in your code you won't find anything since `batch` has a value of `123,321` in your DB.

Comment: so did any of the answers help you? rather rude not to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use find_in_set.but it mostly used to find comma seperated values.

```
$this->db->select('q_set');
$this->db->from("schedule");
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$lot', lot)");
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$batch', batch)");
```

--------------OR---------------

you can try this..

```
  $this->db->select('q_set');
   $this->db->from('schedule as S1');
   $this->db->where('S1.lot',$lot);
   $this->db->where('S1.batch',$batch);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->row();
```

Answer (score 2):

the value of column batch in database is '123,321', and the variable $batch is 123,they are not equal so you can't select it.
you must send a data equal to the one in your database.

try

```
$lot=1;
$batch = 123321;  //or $batch='123,321'  i'm not sure the date type of variable $batch
$dataTest = $this->db->query("select q_set from schedule where lot='$lot' and batch='$batch'")->row();
```

Comment: when i insert seclude. this time insert multiple data in batch .

Comment: what's the data type of batch? string or integer?if it's a integer you need the make the $batch 123321 to select the row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$batch = "123,321";
$lot =1; 

    $dataTest = $this->db->query("select q_set from schedule where lot=".$lot." 
    and batch='".$batch."')->row();
```

or use

```
$batch = "123";
$lot =1; 
$dataTest = $this->db->query("select q_set from schedule where lot=".$lot." 
and batch like '%".$batch."')->row();
```

Comment: i need actual data not like

Comment: use first one then, it seems to be batch is a string

Comment: That `like` won't work anyways, I think `%` should be inside the `'` and at the end

Comment: @kerbholz true :)

Answer (score 2):

Using query builder. Please note if batch is a string it should be `$batch = "123,234"` plus you can't have commas with integers.

```
$this->db->select('q_set');
$this->db->where('lot', $lot);
$this->db->where('batch', $batch);
$q = $this->db->get('schedule');
if ($q->num_rows() > 0}
    print_r($q->row());
} else {
    echo 'no rows';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN Operator,

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')->from($table);
$result = $this->db->where('lot =',$lot);
$result = $this->db->where_in('batch',$batch);
$result = $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

The where_in() operator checks if the value exists in the specified column